# Bootstrap btn-group mis-aligned

Tags: css, button, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a problem with the following code;

```
    <li class="span4">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="" alt="" />
            <div class="caption">
                <h3>Title</h3>
                <div class="clearfix">
                    <div class="pull-right">
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <button class="btn btn-success"><i class="icon-thumbs-up"></i></button>
                            <button class="btn btn-danger"><i class="icon-thumbs-down"></i></button>
                            <button class="btn btn-warning"><i class="icon-star-empty"></i></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
```

The buttons in the thumbnail description look like this;

[image: Problem with buttons]

The main problem I am having, is that these only appear broken *sometimes*. Not always.

It works fine in JSFiddle, but here it is anyway; http://jsfiddle.net/NsKYH/1/

Comment: sometimes? like when the screen is resized or upon refresh?

Comment: could you put your code in **http://jsfiddle.net/**

Comment: @huMptyduMpty It works fine in JSFiddle

Comment: @AndresIlich It appears on first page load, when I refresh the page, it looks fine.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NsKYH/1/ is the JSFiddle

Comment: @jackwilsdon: try adding display: block;
    overflow: hidden; to your btn-group class

Comment: @huMptyduMpty Nope, that didn't fix it. Also, it appears 1/10(ish) times you refresh it, and when you open the page in a new tab.

Comment: @jackwilsdon i can't see it, it looks ok to me no matter what i try.

Comment: Replacing the official bootstrap CSS fixed it for me. I must have modified something within the CSS that messed up the styling of the buttons. That's the moral of the story kids, use a seperate CSS file to modify styles!

Comment: @jackwilsdon post your results in the form of an answer below and approve it, it might help future users as well.

Comment: It has stopped working again :( I'm unsure what is causing it!

Comment: @jackwilsdon post a link to your site so we can take a look.

Comment: It's currently on localhost, but I'll upload it to my server now.

Comment: Any updates on this? I'm having the same issue and can't figure out what the problem might be.

Comment: @jackwilsdon updated your fiddle with the bootstrap stylesheet straight from github and no matter how many times i refresh everything looks ok. Do you think maybe you have a bad, outdated, copy of the bootstrap? Or maybe you are having cache issues? Try clearing your cache or testing in another browser and see if it happens. Also, attach the `bootstrap.css` straight from the githubs repository in your page to double check that its not your stylesheet causing the issues. http://jsfiddle.net/NsKYH/2/show/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be it's better if you define **white-space:nowrap** to `.btn-group` DIV. Write like this:

```
.btn-group{
  white-space:nowrap;
 }    
button{
 white-space:normal;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found some browsers and custom CSS have issues with a white-space between the `button` tag.  Try:

```
<div class="btn-group"><button
    class="btn btn-success"><i class="icon-thumbs-up"></i></button><button
    class="btn btn-danger"><i class="icon-thumbs-down"></i></button><button
    class="btn btn-warning"><i class="icon-star-empty"></i></button></div>
```

<strike>or force the style in a CSS (better idea) or inline *(not a good idea)*:</strike>

```
<div class="btn-group" style="white-space:nowrap;"> ...
```

You will also find this issue with `input-append` (etc.) groupings. Removing the space between html tags seems to fix this.

Answer (score 2):

Simplest fix to prevent wrapping of button group comes from [brianmhunt](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/9939#issuecomment-37682952):

```
.btn-group {
    display: flex;
}
```

Flexbox is [pretty well supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox) these days.